# Angular/Angular material element positioning

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm having some trouble aligning items like mat-grid-list's in angular using the methods I would normally use. Below you'll see that I have a simple grid-list inside a div tag inside a width constrained container. When I try to align the container to the centre of the page, bringing the grid-list along with it using a simple "align-items/text" it doesn't work, and if I use Display:Flex; the mat-grid disappears. Is there a way I can get the constrained "exampleDiv" to the centre of the page without making the mat-grid-list disappear? Thanks

(P.S I tried adding (fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center") in the div tags which didn't work either)

HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="mainContainer">
    

    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2">
            <mat-card class="titleCard"><h5>Edit - Cotswold Wildlife Park</h5></mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="exampleDiv">
        <!-- items to layout horizontally -->
        <div>
            <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="100px">
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    Test
                </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
        </div>
        <mat-card class="exampleCard">...</mat-card>
        etc...
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainContainer {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.titleCard {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}

.exampleCard {
    text-align: center;
}

.exampleDiv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears not centred because your `.exampleDiv` css class has the property `width: 80%`.

Remove that property and it should be positioned like you want it be.